# Switch between 2 walk cycles

Tags: game-engine

I have a walk cycle that consists of 6 animations forward, back, turn left, turn right, Run and jump. I have 6 seperate animations for when a weapon is equipped. How do I switch between the 2 sets of animations with the push of a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be misreading your question, and frankly i'm not very good at blender at all, however I believe you can accomplish this by going to your dope sheet, and selecting action editor as the mode. It should be on the bottom ribbon. Hope I helped.

Comment: i have my regular walk cycle. I'm trying to figure out if i push tab button it equips a weapon then switches to the walk cycle set i have for the character holding a gun.